# Rectifiable Sets

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to give an example of a bounded set of measure zero that is rectifiable and an example of a bounded set of measure zero that is not rectifiable.

I can't think of 1 the top of my head, and for a susbet S of R^n to be rectifiable, we need to have S bounded and BdS measure zero.

Comment: "I can't think of 1 the top of my head, and for a susbet S of R^n to be rectifiable, we need to have S bounded and BdS measure zero." If all you require is that the set be bounded, have measure zero, and be such that the boundary of the set doesn't have measure zero, than any countable dense set will work. (For a bounded measure zero set that *is* rectifiable, what about a singleton set?)

Comment: Uh, why did you flag your own question? Is that a misclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectifiables are somewhat easier to find, so we'll leave them aside for now. As for a non-rectifiable set of measure $0$, you might want to take a look at the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$. This is a concrete and canonical example to the comment of Dave Renfro above.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is Exercise 4 on p.120 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

$\emptyset$ is a bounded set.
$\emptyset$ has measure zero.
$\emptyset$ is rectifiable.

$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is a bounded set.
$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]=\{q_1,q_2,\dots\}$ has measure zero since $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is the union of the countable collection of sets $\{q_1\},\{q_2\},\dots$ and each $\{q_i\}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$. (See Theorem 11.1(b) on p.91.)
$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is not rectifiable since $\int_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} 1$ does not exist. (You can prove this fact by similar way as Example 2 on p.86.)